# arkit3.0 cannot add Reference Object Library in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, arkit

I followed this [tutorial](https://vrgamedevelopment.pro/how-to-track-objects-in-ar-with-arkit-3/) to build using ARKit, but when I try to do **Assets > Create > XR > Reference Object Library** like this tutorial says. I only can create "Reference image library". like this:

[image: picture]

My system Unity 2019.1.0

Comment: The tutorial asks for Unity 19.3 and did you Install AR Foundation & ARKit Package?

Comment: @user14492 yes I installed. I use unity download assistant to download the iossupport.

Comment: You're still using Unity 19.1 when it says 19.3. That is likely the cause. Download it through the [Unity Hub](https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download).

Comment: Yes you are right!  I download this now, try it later.

Comment: Now I in unity 2019.3 ,but when I download the AR Foundation & ARKit Package . It's appear a lot of error...  Like this [pic](https://imgur.com/3Ei8UUS)

Comment: Try clearing them if they go away it's not an issue. If they come back on compile then you prob have mis matched version of packages. Try getting latest non-beta for both

Comment: I can't clean them.So I try to find the newest one. I found the [ARkit plugin](https://imgur.com/maXtMf8). if I need to import all of this file into my unity?

Comment: I don't think you need that. That seems like an old plugin. You should get it from package manager.

Answer (score 0):

I finally download the project from the tutorial.Ｉdon't know why the tutorial asks for Unity 19.3,but the project is 2018.3.8. I download the AR foundation1.5.0 preview and ARKit XR plugin from the package manager. Then appear the opption to create the reference object library.